# Array Of Years in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift

I am using an array of **years** ranged *1950...2022*.

This is my code to get this:

```
let years = (1950...2022).map() { String($0) }
```

But I have to go in descending order like **2022...1950**, and if I write

```
let years = (2022...1950).map() { String($0) }
```

This is giving me the following error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Range requires lowerBound <= upperBound

Did anyone knows how to get it in **descending** order?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `reversed`

`(1950...2022).reversed().map({ String($0) }`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1690025-reversed

Or you can use `stride`

`stride(from: 2022, through: 1950, by: -1).map({ String($0) })`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641347-stride

Comment: `(1950...2022).reversed().map(String.init)`

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
let arr = Array(stride(from: 2022, to: 1950, by: -1))
print(arr)
```